# Any way to make Apache POI write .doc files in UTF-8 through FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, encoding, apache-poi

Is there any way to setup `UTF-8` encoding for a .doc file while using Apache POI with `FileOutputStream`?

This is the code that creates the word document instance:

```
wordDocument = createWordDocument();
```

...

```
public XWPFDocument createWordDocument() {
        wordDocument = new XWPFDocument();
        return wordDocument;
    }
```

This is the code that writes the data to physical file:

```
File resultFile = new File(fileLocation + fileName);
resultFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resultFile);
wordDocument.write(out);
```

Comment: `UTF-8` is the Java default for all string io. Can you post an example how do you write into the XWPFDocument and the result in the xml file.

Comment: `createNewFile()` is not only redundant but wasteful here. `new FileOutputStream(...)` already does exactly that, and now you are forcing it to delete the file you just created as well.

Comment: @PeterMmm this is the place where I write the contents of wordDocument into the out file: `wordDocument.write(out);`. There is a `String` with XML structure which is parsed and written to `XWPFDocument`. Do you want this also?

Comment: @EJP well noted, I have overlooked it somehow.

Comment: The XWPFDocument will write a .docx file which is a Zip file with internal XML-files. Why do you need to control the encoding of the text in those xml-files? Or do you mean something different here?

Comment: @centic I'm not interested in the encoding of the content of the file, but of the file itself. When I am sending these files, they have an encoding when attached and that value is assigned by the JVM, which I want to control. I am currently doing it like this for plain .txt files: `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(resultFile), folderProperties.getEncoding())));` where `getEncoding` returns a `String` with UTF-8.

Comment: .docx is not plain text, so it has no encoding per se. It is a zipped file and thus is a binary format, only the files inside the zip are XML.

Comment: @centic thanks. I think I finally figured what my problem was. It was related to the content-type and encoding of the attachments defined in the mail message I was sending. Spring didn't detect (or isn't supposed) them correctly and whilst the encoding of the files was correct the encoding in the email of those attachments wasn't correct. I found a solution to correct that (I think). Thanks